# Why can I pick out any singer's voice from a choir when I look at them?

Tags: voice, ear-training

Our choir often practises in sections e.g. the sopranos sing their bit while the rest of us wait their turn. I discovered by accident that as I look at any particular singer, I can very clearly hear their individual voice, even if they are quite quiet and there's a dozen singers. I cannot do it if I don't look at them.

Does this phenomenon have a name? Is it common and why does it work this way? How can I expand on this useful skill?

Comment: Not certain so just a comment, but one factor could be that you can correlate their particular timing variations by seeing their mouths and matching that to their vocal contribution. There’s probably all kinds of interesting cognitive research that could be (or has been?) done on this question.

Comment: I'm having trouble answering because I'm skeptical. When you look at a person, do you turn your head to face directly toward them? Does it work if you merely give them side-eye? If the latter, then this is about some kind of cognitive association; if the former, it's about acoustics. I'm skeptical, too, that this skill would work in rooms of other sizes and reverberance (in an echoey cathedral?). If it *does*, I'd have to wonder whether it's just confirmation bias (how do you *know* you're hearing that one person's voiceprint, not just imagining it?)

Comment: Other scientific-method ways to zero in: Does this work when watching another choir in concert, or only with the singers whose voices you've grown used to over frequent rehearsals?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the skepticism. Our choir-master can tell "Sarah is flat on this note" when we are all singing together in harmony so why is this hard to believe?

Comment: @AndyBonner I agree with Mr. Boy. I taught guitar to a room full of third graders once, and I could hear clearly who was playing well and who wasn’t, and who was in tune and who wasn’t, even when they were all playing at once.

Comment: @ToddWilcox And indeed, as an orchestra director, I can do the same with violins. I can even identify the offending instrument by familiarity with its individual timbre. But 1) I consciously co-ordinate visual cues ("*Somebody's* flat! I'll look for bow movement that matches the start of the flat notes"), and 2) I of course could only recognize an instrument by its individual sound if I was very familiar with it. To be clear, Mr. Boy, I don't doubt that you can do what you describe, I'm just not sure it's anything other than a phenomenon of acoustics and observation.

Comment: (Well, actually, maybe I do harbor a bit of doubt; if we wanted to be super-scientific about it, we definitely would have to rule out the possibility that we *think* we hear a particular person. And frequently as a conductor I'd make lucky/educated guesses to preserve the "ears in the back of his head" aura.

Comment: Another important aspect to consider is that with "lower" levels of performers, it's easier to have visual/acoustic clues of the player how's wrong: their "mistakes" are often much more clear, and the group is also often less "homogeneous" (there are many more differences in precision of tuning, rhythm/tempo and dynamics). Also, it's easier to associate a voice with a person as soon as there's any way to achieve that association (including small visual/acoustic clues), especially if you already know that voice; if the ambient is small (or the listener is close to the singer) and acoustics ->

Comment: -> allows it, our hearing and focusing on voices naturally allows us to focus more on a specific person. This is also related to the capacity of [attention](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attention#Selective_and_visual), specifically the [selective auditory attention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selective_auditory_attention). This is similar to the way we can often be able to focus on a conversation in a large crowd as soon as someone says our name or talks about a very specific subject that is somehow important for us.

Comment: @AndyBonner also, especially if it is an amateur choir, you might know that Sarah is flat because, well, of course it's Sarah who's flat.  Amateur singers tend to be consistent in their faults, whether being flat or sharp, dragging or rushing, and so on.

Comment: There are additional cues specific to the voice, too: vowel quality, volume/quality/timing of consonants, vibrato level/rate, variations in timbre between the different registers — most of which have visual as well as audible effects. (And, as phoog suggests, while in a good professional choir you'd hope that many of those things would be controlled and moderated and fairly homogeneous, in an amateur choir they're often unfortunately not.)

Answer (score 10):

That's known as the [cocktail party effect](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocktail_party_effect) (being able to focus on particular speakers in a noisy environment), in this case aided by crossmodal sensory integration and attention.  It's one of those things where it is hard to get anywhere close to human performance with computing because it is a core tenet of visual and auditory processing that tends to be continually exercised.

Comment: This specific part sounded particularly relevant: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocktail_party_effect#Visual_correlates